# What is the idiom for `flash('Helpful Message')` when one is sending/receiving JSON?

Tags: python, json, jinja2, flask-restful

In `base.html` of my Jinja2 HTML template files I have

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div>
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This works well. Wherever I have

```
from flask import render_template

@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if is_invalid():
        flash('Invalid')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

the file `index.html` is returned and the appropriate flashed messages appear, because `index.html` is derived from `base.html`.

It get slightly more complicated if I am *not* updating the entire page. The file `details.html`, which is still derived from `base.html`, is too expensive to redraw. When the user triggers an event, a (JSON) API call is received by the server, and the response is interpreted in JavaScript to update (parts of) `details.html`.

I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. What is the appropriate idiom for `flash('Helpful Message')` when one is sending/receiving JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to do it in javascript not jinja

often you will create an "error" div at the top

```
<div class="error" id="errorMessage"></div>
```

then you will populate it on response

```
fetch(someurl).then(r=>r.json()).then(data=>{
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerText = "Helpful message"
})
```

of coarse you might be able to just get away with `alert("Helpful Message")` or you may want to go with some (javascript) UI library that provides a simple and more robust alert messaging system